# 'validates_confirmation_of :password' fails but "Password can't be blank" message displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, form-helpers

I'm going through the [Railscast on "authentication from scratch"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) and following along step by step.

The form is reporting that "Password can't be blank" even though the error is supposed to be that the password and the password_confirmation does not match. I.e. when I type in a password and purposely type in a wrong confirmation, the error message displayed is still "Password can't be blank".

This is what my User model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
    validates_presence_of :email 
    validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

How can I make it so that the error message displays "Passwords don't match" or something similar if the error is in fact mismatching password and password_confirmation?

**_form.html.erb partial**

```
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :pass)
    end
end
```

Comment: can you please post your user controller and form

Comment: @AmitSharma posted it above. It is mostly standard stuff from `rails generate Scaffold`. I modified some parts of form for password_confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in following code.

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :pass)
  end
```

Please replace above method with following.

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Please reply if you get any error.

Comment: That was it! That was the problem and your solution solved it exactly. Thank you so much. You are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Validate the presence of the confirmation and not of the password. Then it should work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :on => :create
    validates_presence_of :email 
    validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

See the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#confirmation) for this.

Comment: Hmm.. now it just says "password_confirmation can't be blank". Changing my code to match the Rails Guide gives same result.